# Tradução da palavra flush

Tags: terminologia, input-output

Estou preparando material de referência sobre programação funcional usando a linguagem [OCaml](http://ocaml.org/) e gostaria de uma boa tradução para o português da palavra `flush`, comumente encontrada na descrição de operações de entrada e saída.

Mais precisamente, estou precisando de uma tradução para a expressão `flush the standard output`.

Embora esteja escrevendo sobre OCaml, o conceito abordado aplica-se à grande maioria das linguagens de programação.

Answer (score 10):

Não é uma tradução muito bonita, mas no sentido estrito, seria ["descarga"](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/flush).

Em programação, o sentido é estendido para o esvaziamento de um conteúdo, como um buffer de memória. *Streams* de arquivos são os mais comuns de terem operações de *flush*. Ou seja, neste caso, uma chamada a um método *flush* seria para descarregar o conteúdo da memória para o armazenamento permanente.

Para o caso de buffers de saída (*standard output* é um deles), a descarga de dados seria da memória para a tela de terminal em que isso possa ser lido.

Comment: Se uma *"stream"* é um rio, um fluxo [d'água], uma corrente [idem], então faz todo sentido que esvaziá-la seja uma descarga...

Comment: Mas vamo combinar que é feio pra c...

Comment: Talvez "liberar" também seja uma boa opção, apesar de que "descarregar" ainda me parece mais correto (mesmo sendo mais feio).

Comment: @LuizVieira "Liberar" está mais para *free* do que para *flush*. A conotação é bem separada entre ambos no inglês.

Comment: Sim, é verdade, principalmente no sentido de garantir que o que está pendente seja gravado. Mas como *flush* advém de "fluxo repentino" (tanto que é usado não apenas para se referir à descarga no toilet, mas também para a vermelhidão na face), a intenção da frase também poderia ser a de liberar (ou limpar o) espaço para novas operações. Como eu disse, acho que a sua sugestão é a mais correta, mas achei que ainda assim valia a menção em um comentário (não em uma resposta). :)

Answer (score 7):

Eu acho que uma tradução razoável seria **descarregar**. Assim, "*flush standard output*" seria traduzido para "*descarregar a saída padrão*".

Você pode argumentar (e eu concordaria) que o termo descarregar soa um pouco estranho. Mas mesmo o termo original em inglês, *flush*, se você for ver é algo bem estranho e inadequado.

O significado mesmo seria algo como "*completar as operações de saída pendentes armazenadas no buffer*".

Comment: *"completar as operações de saída pendentes"* é bonito, mas é enorme. :P