# Qual a diferença entre as implementações de IDisposable?

Tags: c#, garbage-collector

Confesso que ainda não entendi tudo sobre como manipular a destruição de um objeto no **C#** e agora, ao estar testando o **Visual Studio 2015 Preview**, ao estar implementando uma classe de conexão com banco de dados fui incluir a herança de `IDisposable` e utilizei a opção ***Implement interface with Dispose pattern***.

Então foi incluído o seguinte código em minha classe:

```cs
#region IDisposable Support
private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a 
        // finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.

        disposedValue = true;
    }
}

// TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code 
// to free unmanaged resources.
// ~DBConnection() {
//   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
//   Dispose(false);
// }

// This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
public void Dispose()
{
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    Dispose(true);
    // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
    // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
#endregion
```

Não consegui entender esses comentários com ***TODOs*** sobre o método *finalizer* `~DBConnection()`, sobre o `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` e sobre o método `Dispose(bool disposing)` e todo seu conteúdo...

Verificando ainda outras opções vi a seguinte implementação:

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
}
```

E claro, temos a seguinte:

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Que eu implementaria como geralmente é mostrado em exemplos na web:

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection = null;
    }
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Bom, sobre o primeiro exemplo de implementação com todos aqueles comentários, entendi que há ali uma explicação das opções de implementação.

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender a diferença entre esses métodos e as indicações do primeiro método com os comentários?

Comment: Você só precisa implementar `IDisposable` se estiver usando recursos não gerenciados pela CLR. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: mas @bfavaretto, quais seriam os "recursos não gerenciados"? E qual a diferença entre as formas de implementação de `IDisposable`? Por fim, depois eu vou criar uma pergunta sobre gerenciamento de conexões no c#. Pool de conexões, mais de um `command` e `reader` ... vamos ver.. obrigado!

Comment: James, tudo que você programa em .net é compilado para uma linguagem intermediária interpretada pela máquina virtual do .net (a CLR). Esse tipo de código é gerenciado pela CLR (que cuida de coleta de lixo, entre outras burocracias). Código compilado pra linguagem de máquina (por exemplo, escrito em C) pode ser integrado no seu programa, mas não é gerenciado pela CLR e você precisa cuidar manualmente de certos detalhes. Mas vou parar por aqui e deixar pros experts em .net responderem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Várias coisas. Vou traduzir o primeiro trecho de código pra ficar mais claro, e discutir cada método:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: fazer dispose dos managed objects.
        }

        // TODO: liberar recursos unmanaged (unmanaged objects) e fazer override do finalizador.
        // TODO: campos grandes devem receber valor null.

        disposedValue = true;
    }
}
```

Primeiro preciso explicar o que são objetos *managed* e *unmanaged*.

- Objetos *managed* são aqueles que estão sendo controlados diretamente pelo *garbage collector*. Ou seja, objetos de classes do seu sistema normalmente são *managed*;
- Objetos *unmanaged* são o inverso. Um *provider* de banco de dados, por exemplo, escrito em uma DLL que não seja do .NET. Normalmente objetos assim possuem um procedimento próprio de liberação de memória , especificado pelo provedor da tecnologia.

Dentro do `if` você deve colocar todo e qualquer código **adicional** que permita a liberação imediata dos recursos da máquina. Zerar variáveis grandes em memória, por exemplo.

Logo abaixo (na parte de recursos *unmanaged*) você deve colocar todo e qualquer código que envolva uso de recursos que o .NET não possua qualquer controle, como por exemplo um *buffer* de impressora ou de uma controladora de disco. Num contexto de banco de dados, fechar a conexão, (que usa um *socket* que não seja .NET, mas que esteja ligado a um código .NET).

A ideia desse destrutor:

```
~DBConnection() 
{
    // Não mude este código. Ele só está aqui a título de exemplo.
    Dispose(false);
}
```

É evitar quaisquer liberações automáticas de memória pelo *garbage collector*. Você indica ao *garbage collector* que seu código irá coordenar a destruição do objeto.

Vamos voltar ao exemplo dos *buffers* lentos (discos e impressoras). A conexão com as controladoras demora. Se você libera o objeto antes, perde a referência para se comunicar com a controladora e garantir que tudo foi feito certo. Isto é crítico quando você precisa executar, por exemplo, alguma operação de [*flush*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58432/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-palavra-flush/58434#58434). Liberar o objeto antes pode fazer com que a comunicação seja interrompida e seja causado algum problema de inconsistência entre as partes na comunicação.

Um *socket* de banco de dados é um caso clássico disso. O fechamento da conexão é recomendado ser feito depois do `if`.

Por fim:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection = null;
    }
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

`GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` indica que o destrutor não deve ser chamado imediatamente. Fechar a conexão é uma cadeia de procedimentos, e o código deve garantir que o objeto exista o máximo de tempo possível para evitar problemas.

Passado algum tempo, o *garbage collector* fará verificações de rotina e, ao verificar que o objeto não possui mais referências, eliminará o objeto. Isto é mais seguro do que pedir a liberação imediata do objeto.

Answer (score -1):

**James**, a primeira coisa a se entender é que o Garbage Collector (ou *Coleto de Lixo*) é automático.

O `Dispose Pattern` seria então um padrão de projeto que visa manipular o estado de destruição de objetos pela CLR (Common Language Runtime).

Em outras palavras, você pode indicar quando um objeto poderá ou não ser destruído implementando a classe descrita na pergunta.

`GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` diz ao CRL para não finalizar o objeto especificado (no caso, `connection`).

De períodos em períodos, o GB faz uma reciclagem para verificar se os objetos da memória "heap" estão ou não sendo utilizados pela aplicação e efetua as operações para limpá-los da memória.

O `Dispose Pattern` desenvolve então maneiras conceituais e práticas de para gerenciarmos estes objetos "disposables" forçando-os "sumirem" da memória ou suprimindo a requisição automática de eliminar da memória.

Comment: Só sobre o `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`, ele suprime a finalização pelo *Garbage Collector* da classe que compõe o `connection`, e não a `connection` em si.

Comment: Não entendi...a ```connection``` é o objeto a ser disposable pelo GB. ```SuppressFinalize``` está informando o GB que esse objeto foi limpo totalmente

Comment: Não.. eu tenho algo como `public class DBConnection { private SqlConnection connection; ... }` então `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` diz que `DBConnection` foi limpa, e não `connection`.