# Pool de conexões com ADO.NET e Dispose de SqlConnection, o que é correto fazer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, conexão, ado.net, garbage-collector

Fiz ontem uma pergunta ontem sobre [Qual a diferença entre as implementações de IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70839/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-implementa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-idisposable)

Estava implementando uma classe para ajudar a obter instâncias de `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` métodos `ExecuteSql` etc. E ao implementar a interface `IDisposable` vi algumas coisas que não conheço sobre o gerenciamento de memória no .Net.

Isso me fez lembrar também de uma vez que estava implementando uma classe para o mesmo fim e que acabei incluindo na **Connection String** a opção `Pooling=false` pois estava tendo problemas ao efetuar o método `Dispose` das instâncias de `SqlConnection` mesmo após o real término do ciclo da requisição.

Quando fiz isso tinha uma classe mais ou menos assim:

```cs
public class DbConnection : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public DbConnection()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection("string de conexão");
    }

    #region outros métodos ...

    ~DbConnection()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Dispose();
            connection = null;
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Essa, inclusive, é similar a da outra questão que criei.

Foi pesquisando que encotrei comentários sobre o tal Pool de Conexões e que ao usar `Dispose()` explicitamente de `SqlConnection` que poderíamos estar causando confusão no controle do Pool de Conexões. Por fim, que uma solução seria desabilitar o Pool de Conexões.

Permitir o Pool de Conexões é benéfico para o desempenho da aplicação?

Permitindo o Pool de Conexões, qual é a forma correta de gerenciar as instâncias de `SqlConnection`, não efetuando o `Dispose()`?

Por padrão o SqlConnection permite apenas um SqlDataReader por instância de SqlConnection, certo, para obter mais de um é preciso adicionar a opção `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` na Connection String, isso causa perda de desempenho na aplicação?

Answer (score 2):

Cara eu tenho uma classe muito otimizada e boa que utilizo nos projetos aqui, usando Generics tu pode até escolher qual tipo de Classe de acesso a dados você quer usar, fiz até testes de performance:

```
private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlServerConnection"];

private static DataTable Read<TS, T>(string query) where TS : IDbConnection, new() where T : class, IDbDataAdapter, IDisposable, new()
{
    using (var conn = new TS())
    {
        using (var da = new T())
        {
            using (da.SelectCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
                da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode usar assim:

```
var result = Read<SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter>("SELECT * FROM [SuaTabela]");
```

Não precisa se preocupar com o Dispose, pois a memória é gerenciada e liberada após a chamada do método usando o `using { }`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas estou mesmo é procurando pelo conceito.