# Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collector, dispose

- Em .NET, em que circunstâncias se deve usar `GC.SuppressFinalize()`?
- Quais as vantagens da utilização deste método?

**Obs:** Encontrei resposta no [SO-en: When should I use GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize) Como não tinha algo relacionado em `pt-br` resolvi reproduzir a pergunta aqui para que tenhamos uma fonte em português.

Comment: Imagino que deseja essencialmente aquela excelente resposta. Sabe inglês? Sabe que você pode postar a resposta por conta própria? Deseja fazer isto? Ou prefere que alguém poste aqui?

Comment: Não pretendo responder a princípio, somente se alguém não responder por um longo tempo (1 semana).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar entender o tema:

- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre as implementações de IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70839/101)
- [O que significa '~' na frente do construtor de uma classe C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101)

Existem algumas classes que possuem "recursos" que vão além do conteúdo da memória gerenciada. Nestes casos a própria classe deve tomar alguma atitude de como proceder a destruição do seu conteúdo. Ela precisa de um método finalizador. Isto é muito comum na implementação do padrão de disposição (interface `IDisposable`). O finalizador é útil em todas as situações que a destruição do objeto deve ser personalizada e vai além da desalocação da memória, que só o GC pode proceder, do jeito que bem entender.

Esta é uma forma de indicar ao GC que ele não deve chamar o finalizador, já que ele foi chamado pela classe em momento anterior. Se ele for chamado, ele tentará executar uma limpeza que já foi realizada e provavelmente ocorrerá algum problema.

Exemplo de implementação:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                // chamado pelo myClass.Dispose(). 
                // OK usar quaisquer referências para objetos privados
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { // necessário para a interface IDisposable
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~MyClass() { //método finalizador (destrutor)
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/SupressFinalize.cs).

A disposição só deve ser usada em casos específicos, onde realmente ela é necessária. Não pode-se ficar tentado forçar a liberação de recursos quando apenas a memória gerenciada é alocada. Isto não dá certo. A liberação de memória só pode ser realizada pelo GC. O método [`GC.SuppressFinalize()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_GC_SuppressFinalize_System_Object_) só informa que a finalização já foi realizada, não que a liberação de memória ocorreu. Nem poderia fazer isto. A alocação de memória da CLR é feita de maneira toda própria e de forma integrada, a aplicação não tem qualquer controle sobre ela. Não dá para controlar uma parte da alocação. É uma coisa só.

Para quem não sabe bem o que fazer nestes casos, é melhor seguir a receita acima. Mas seria bom estudar bastante o assunto antes de criar uma classe que dependa de recursos externos. A maioria das aplicações não precisam disto. Basta consumir o que já existe.

Não há problema de performance em usá-lo. A não ser que o algoritmo específico usado no finalizador tenha algum problema de performance próprio, mas não será culpa deste método do GC.

Outra [pergunta do SO sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038571/221800).

Answer (score 3):

Ele deve ser utilizado quando a classe é finalizada.

Quando for utilizar a recomendação é utilizar uma implementação de `IDisposable`:

Essa é uma implementação que eu fiz em um projeto:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
public void Dispose(bool v)
{
    if (v)
    {
        if (db != null) { db.Dispose(); db = null; }
    }
}
```

**Atualizando**
A resposta atual estava errada, estou atualizando conforma a dica do Maniero no comentário.

Os objetos que implementam a interface `IDisposable` podem chamar esse método de execução, para impedir que o coletor de lixo chame `Object.Finalize()` em um objeto que não exige isso. Normalmente, isso é feito para evitar que o finalizador libere recursos não gerenciados que já foram libertados pela implementação `IDisposable.Dispose()`.