# Insert C# data.sqlclient

Tags: c#, visual-studio

boa tarde!

Estou iniciando em C# e estou com uma duvida de parameter

ja varios tipo de insert sql server. Ai estou com dificuldade nessa parte

diz: não é possivel converter de "system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter"

segue o codigo:

```
string strSQL = @"INSERT INTO TESTE (Razão_Social) VALUES ( @parm1 )";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (strSQL, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@parm1, txt_razao.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();



            MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado !!!!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `AddWithValue` recebe dois parâmetros: `(string, object)`, segundo a documentação: [AddWitValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

Logo, deve ser assim:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", txt_razao.Text);`

Aproveitando, para ajudar a controlar e fechar seu objeto de comando, coloque seu código num bloco `using`, assim:

```
conn.Open();
string strSQL = @"INSERT INTO TESTE (Razão_Social) VALUES ( @parm1 )";
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", txt_razao.Text);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: obrigado resolveu, ou duvida? porque tenho que usar using no sqlcommand?

Comment: isso daria uma resposta :) não sei se conhece o conceito de *Dispose*, não conhecer essa pergunta explica bem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70839/57220
basicamente, objetos que usam recursos como arquivos, conexões de rede entre outros, precisam liberar esses recursos, fechar os arquivos, as conexões, etc... por exemplo o `SqlCommand`, tem o método `Close` para isso.. para facilitar essas operações, algumas classes implementam a interface `IDisposable`, que exige que implemente o método `Dispose`, onde geralmente são liberados os recursos...

Comment: Para facilitar o trabalho, e evitar que precise sempre chamar esse método, foi criar o comando `using` (não confunda com o `using` no início do arquivo onde tem as referências dos namespaces usados). O `using` automaticamente executa o método `Dispose` quando termina, ou seja, quando termina seu bloco no fechar chaves `}` ele vai executar o `cmd.Close()` e tudo mais que for preciso para liberar os recursos do problema, simples e limpo, e ótimo caso vc esquecer de fazer isso :)
Só funciona com objetos que implementam o `IDisposible`, o `SqlConnection` também por exemplo

Comment: espero term explicado bem, qualquer dúvida só perguntar, e tb tem outras perguntas sobre isso aqui no site :)

Comment: pow, entendi legal agr!, porem uma duvida  o SqlConnection.close nao resolveria a situação ?

Comment: sim resolve, pode colocar ele inclusive num bloco de `using` tbm :)

Comment: obrigado. encerro por aqui. Muita boa explicação !!!!